# Mysql Query Optimizer behaviour not consistent

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

For the same query, mysql 5.6.4 is giving two different query plans. What can be the cause for this?

```
explain 
select this_.id 
from coupons_new this_ 
inner join coupons_config c1_ on this_.coupon_config_id=c1_.id 
left outer join coupon_products_mapping couponprod4_ on c1_.id=couponprod4_.coupon_config_id 
where (   c1_.type in ('RULE', 'SEGMENT') 
       or (    c1_.type='EMAIL' 
           and c1_.user_email_id='xxx@joulroad.com')) 
  and c1_.expiry>'2021-07-01 03:49:50.0' 
  and this_.available_count>0 
  and this_.active=1 
  and c1_.is_visible=1;


+----+-------------+--------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+---------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type | possible_keys                                                   | key                 | key_len | ref           | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+---------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c1_          | ref  | PRIMARY,is_active,type_email,type_segment,type_expiry,type_rule | is_active           | 1       | const         |  206 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | this_        | ref  | fk_coupon_config,active_count                                   | fk_coupon_config    | 8       | userDB.c1_.id |    1 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | couponprod4_ | ref  | fk_coupon_config_id                                             | fk_coupon_config_id | 8       | userDB.c1_.id |    1 | NULL        |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+---------------+------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

```
explain 
select this_.id 
from coupons_new this_ 
inner join coupons_config c1_ on this_.coupon_config_id=c1_.id 
left outer join coupon_products_mapping couponprod4_ on c1_.id=couponprod4_.coupon_config_id 
where (   c1_.type in ('RULE', 'SEGMENT') 
       or (    c1_.type='EMAIL' 
           and c1_.user_email_id='xxxxx@xxx.com')) 
  and c1_.expiry>'2021-07-01 03:49:50.0' 
  and this_.available_count>0 
  and this_.active=1 
  and c1_.is_visible=1;


+----+-------------+--------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-------------------------------+---------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type   | possible_keys                                                   | key                 | key_len | ref                           | rows    | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-------------------------------+---------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | this_        | ref    | fk_coupon_config,active_count                                   | active_count        | 2       | const                         | 1370900 | Using index condition |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c1_          | eq_ref | PRIMARY,is_active,type_email,type_segment,type_expiry,type_rule | PRIMARY             | 8       | userDB.this_.coupon_config_id |       1 | Using where           |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | couponprod4_ | ref    | fk_coupon_config_id                                             | fk_coupon_config_id | 8       | userDB.this_.coupon_config_id |       1 | NULL                  |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-------------------------------+---------+-----------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Table indexes**

```
show indexes from coupons_new;
```

| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| coupons_new | 0 | PRIMARY | 1 | id | A | 2721794 | NULL | NULL |  | BTREE |  |  |
| coupons_new | 0 | id | 1 | id | A | 2721794 | NULL | NULL |  | BTREE |  |  |
| coupons_new | 0 | coupon_code | 1 | coupon_code | A | 2721794 | NULL | NULL | YES | BTREE |  |  |
| coupons_new | 1 | fk_coupon_config | 1 | coupon_config_id | A | 126 | NULL | NULL |  | BTREE |  |  |
| coupons_new | 1 | active_count | 1 | active | A | 2 | NULL | NULL | YES | BTREE |  |  |
| coupons_new | 1 | active_count | 2 | available_count | A | 28 | NULL | NULL | YES | BTREE |  |  |

```
show indexes from coupons_config;
```

| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| coupons_config | 0 | PRIMARY | 1 | id | A | 323 | NULL | NULL |  | BTREE |  |  |
| coupons_config | 1 | is_active | 1 | is_visible | A | 4 | NULL | NULL |  | BTREE |  |  |
| coupons_config | 1 | type_email | 1 | type | A | 8 | NULL | NULL | YES | BTREE |  |  |
| coupons_config | 1 | type_email | 2 | user_email_id | A | 24 | NULL | NULL | YES | BTREE |  |  |
| coupons_config | 1 | type_email | 3 | expiry | A | 323 | NULL | NULL | YES | BTREE |  |  |
| coupons_config | 1 | type_email | 4 | is_visible | A | 323 | NULL | NULL |  | BTREE |  |  |
| coupons_config | 1 | type_segment | 1 | type | A | 8 | NULL | NULL | YES | BTREE |  |  |
| coupons_config | 1 | type_segment | 2 | user_segment | A | 12 | NULL | NULL | YES | BTREE |  |  |
| coupons_config | 1 | type_expiry | 1 | type | A | 8 | NULL | NULL | YES | BTREE |  |  |
| coupons_config | 1 | type_expiry | 2 | expiry | A | 323 | NULL | NULL | YES | BTREE |  |  |
| coupons_config | 1 | type_expiry | 3 | is_visible | A | 323 | NULL | NULL |  | BTREE |  |  |
| coupons_config | 1 | type_rule | 1 | type | A | 8 | NULL | NULL | YES | BTREE |  |  |
| coupons_config | 1 | type_rule | 2 | user_attributes | A | 64 | NULL | NULL | YES | BTREE |  |  |

```
show indexes from coupon_products_mapping;
```

| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| coupon_products_mapping | 0 | PRIMARY | 1 | id | A | 131 | NULL | NULL |  | BTREE |  |  |
| coupon_products_mapping | 0 | type_val | 1 | val | A | 131 | NULL | NULL |  | BTREE |  |  |
| coupon_products_mapping | 0 | type_val | 2 | type | A | 131 | NULL | NULL | YES | BTREE |  |  |
| coupon_products_mapping | 0 | type_val | 3 | coupon_config_id | A | 131 | NULL | NULL |  | BTREE |  |  |
| coupon_products_mapping | 1 | fk_coupon_config_id | 1 | coupon_config_id | A | 131 | NULL | NULL |  | BTREE |  |  |

```
CREATE TABLE `coupons_new` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `coupon_code` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `coupon_config_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `available_count` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created_by` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `coupon_code` (`coupon_code`),
  KEY `fk_coupon_config` (`coupon_config_id`),
  KEY `active_count` (`active`,`available_count`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_coupon_config` FOREIGN KEY (`coupon_config_id`) REFERENCES `coupons_config` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3320112 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `coupons_config` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_email_id` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_attributes` varchar(20) DEFAULT 'xxxxxxxxxx',
  `user_segment` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` enum('EMAIL','RULE','SEGMENT') DEFAULT NULL,
  `discount_info` text,
  `extras` text,
  `start_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `expiry` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `per_user_limit` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `overall_limit` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `min_order_amount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `coupon_prefix` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_bulk_config` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `is_visible` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `coupon_creation_rule_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `is_active` (`is_visible`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `type_email` (`type`,`user_email_id`,`expiry`,`is_visible`),
  KEY `type_segment` (`type`,`user_segment`),
  KEY `type_expiry` (`type`,`expiry`,`is_visible`),
  KEY `type_rule` (`type`,`user_attributes`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=420 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

```
CREATE TABLE `coupon_products_mapping` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `coupon_config_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('BRAND','CAT','UPID') DEFAULT NULL,
  `val` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `type_val` (`val`,`type`,`coupon_config_id`),
  KEY `fk_coupon_config_id` (`coupon_config_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_coupon_config_id` FOREIGN KEY (`coupon_config_id`) REFERENCES `coupons_config` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=174 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

What am I missing here, will be great if someone can help.

Comment: If both query plans are comparable in performance, than a change in the statistics might cause MySQL to flip flop between these two query plans.

Comment: Performance is not even close. In one case it take 1-2ms, in the other 20-60sec depending on load.

Comment: coupon_products_mapping: i have reduced the selected columns while posting

Comment: *For the same query, mysql 5.6.4 is giving two different query plans. What can be the cause for this?* The difference in table data and/or statistic. If the data arrays are the same then execute ANALYZE TABLE on both systems and all tables.

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE output added

Comment: @Akina: It is the same system. It starts misbehaving abruptly

Comment: I ran analyze, still it is showing the less optimized query plan

Comment: ```PRIMARY KEY (`id`), UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)``` wtf??? what is the reason to have 2 copies of the same index?

Comment: In `coupon_products_mapping` - alter to ```UNIQUE KEY `type_val` (`coupon_config_id`,`val`,`type`)``` and remove ```KEY `fk_coupon_config_id` (`coupon_config_id`)```. Of course only when `val, type` prefix not needed for another queries.

Comment: *I ran analyze, still it is showing the less optimized query plan* This is possible. Try to revert to the first plan using reordering tables in FROM and STRAIGHT_JOIN and maybe index hints (and ensure that the performance increases).

Comment: Thanks for spotting the duplicated index in both tables. Will change that

We can use index hints, but is there any other workaround for this? As in the query was behaving normally for a month and today it started spiking. This can happen with any query in the system. Do you recommend using index hints for all production queries to avoid this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234407/discussion-between-user2307034-and-akina).

Comment: Also to add, this happens when we are using OR in the where clause

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible reasons for the inconsistency.  I suspect `OR` is the biggest problem.  Instead of pursuing the reasons, let's speed up the queries.

When the Optimizer picks `this_` as the 'first' table, `INDEX(active, available_count)` is good.  But replacing it with this would be better because of being 'covering':

```
INDEX(active, available_count, coupon_config_id)
```

For the other order, replace `INDEX(coupon_config_id)` by

```
INDEX(coupon_config_id, active, available_count)
```

The `OR` makes `c1_` trickier

```
    where  ( c1_.type in ('RULE', 'SEGMENT')
              or  ( c1_.type='EMAIL'
                      and  c1_.user_email_id='xxx@joulroad.com')
           )
      and  c1_.expiry>'2021-07-01 03:49:50.0'
      and  c1_.is_visible=1;
```

Without rewriting the query, replace `INDEX(is_visible) with

```
INDEX(is_visible, expiry)
```

`OR` can be optimized by using `UNION`.  Either make a derived table with a `UNION` or use the `UNION` at the outer level.  Change the `WHERE` and add indexes:

```
WHERE c1_.type in ('RULE', 'SEGMENT')

INDEX(is_visible, type, expiry)

WHERE c1_.type='EMAIL' and  c1_.user_email_id='xxx@joulroad.com'

INDEX(user_email_id, is_visible, type, expiry)
```

Side notes:

- Redundant index

  ```
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),     -- this is a UNIQUE key, so
    UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`), -- is redundant, DROP it
  ```
- In general, when a table has both `INDEX(a)` and `INDEX(a,b)`, the former is redundant and should be dropped.
- If `coupon_products_mapping` is a many:many mapping table (mapping val+type to coupon_config_id), then get rid of `id` and promote the `UNIQUE` key to be `PRIMARY`.  More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table